# Understanding bicomplex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I found by chance, the set of [Bicomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessarine). These numbers took particularly my attention because of their similarity to my previous personal research and [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373357/4-dimensional-numbers). I should say that I can't really understand the fact that $j^2=+1$ (and must of other abstract algebra) without using matricial interpretations. When I look a bit on the Bicomplex numbers, the think that surprised me a lot was the fact that $ij=ji=k$ and $k^2=-1$. Because using matricial representations, we get :
$$ij=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ji=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
So, $ij$ should be different then $ji$. Then if we define $k=ij$ or $k=ji$, we get both way $$k^2= I$$
Looked at the Wikipedia article and did some internet search but couldn't find a matricial representation for the bicomplex $k$. So I wanna ask some clarifications about where from the relations $ij=ji$ and $k^2=-1$ come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate algebras suiting any such set of constraints, but the catch is you might wind up collapsing more than you wanted to :) In the following, I'm glossing over a few details in the interest of getting broader points across.

As a toy example, think of the polynomial ring $\Bbb R[x]$ in one unknown. We can pass to a [ring quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$. The $(x^2+1)$ bit denotes the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+1$. Quotients rings can only be formed by using an ideal underneath, so this is necessary. The idea behind a quotient ring is that everything in the ideal is "the same as zero now". So, in particular, $x^2+1=0$, and thus $x^2=-1$. (Actually I can't say that $x^2=-1$, it is really that they are part of the same equivalence class, which we might have to deal with later... ). So, using the map $x\mapsto i$, it turns out $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)\cong \Bbb C$!

In the case of your ring, think of the polynomial ring $\Bbb R[x,y]$ in two unknowns $x$. We want to force $ij=ji$ and $i^2=-1$ and $j^2=1$, so we can try to do something simliar in this polynomial ring by looking at the quotient ring $\Bbb R[x,y]/( x^2+1, y^2-1)$. In this ring, we know that all three of those polynomials in the bottom are "the same as zero", so $x^2=-1$ and $y^2=1$ look a lot like $i,j$ and their commutation relations! Maybe we should map $x\to i$, $y\to j$.

What about $k$? Well, we know we want $xy$ to be what represents $k$. Does $(xy)^2=1$? Well sure, since $(xy)^2=x^2y^2=-1*1=-1$. It turns out that indeed, under this map $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2-1)\cong \Bbb B$ the bicomplex numbers.

This method allows you to construct lots of commutative rings satisfying relations you have in mind. Noncommutative ones can be constructed too, it's just that rather than the polynomial ring you use $\Bbb F\langle x,y\dots \rangle$ to denote a polynomial ring in which you don't assume the unknowns can commute. (That's assumed in normal polynomial rings.)

Remember we were looking at Clifford algebras before? They can be constructed using these noncommuting polynomial rings. Suppose you have your multiplication table of $e_i$'s set up so that $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$ for every $i\neq j$, and $e_i^2=c_i\in \Bbb R$.

Then the quotient ring $\Bbb R \langle e_1,\dots,e_n \rangle/(e_1^2-c_1,\dots e_n^2-c_n,e_1e_2+e_2e_1,e_1e_3+e_3e_1,\dots, )$ is isomorphic to that algebra.

Comment: So what's wrong with the matrix representations?

Comment: I know this is overload, and don't worry if you don't get it all. Just try to take away this idea that you can make new rings by thinking of a big ring and then forcing some relations to hold with this "quotient" process. It will make a lot more sense when you start working with some basic abstract algebra :)

Comment: @moray95 Er... well that just isn't a matrix representation of the biquaternions. Isn't that the representation of the other algebra we were talking about which I told you *wasn't* the same as the biquaternions?

Comment: The $i$ and $j$ are actually the same ones... That's why I used these representations. They are the same numbers.

Comment: @moray95 No, it is not the same representation. The two rings have completely different properties. $i$ and $j$ do not denote the same thing here as they did before.

Comment: Why not? In both cases are they not the imaginary unit and the the split-complex unit? In the wiki article it also says "real tessarines $t=w+yj$, also called split-complex numbers". $i^2=-1$ and $j^2=+1$ in each cases... I can't see any difference here.

Comment: $i$ and $j$ do not permanently mean those two matrices all the time. $i$ $j$ and $k$ are frequently used as "basis vectors", but what they square to depends on context. For example, in quaternions, $i,j,k$ all square to -1. They have a totally different representation because they have totally different properties, but mathematicians have to recycle letters of the alphabet because there are only so many to use!

Comment: I never said that they permanently mean these matrices but in this situation, it is strictly the same numbers no? The imaginary unit and the split-complex unit.

Comment: @moray95 OK, that statement helps me see your point of view a little! You are attaching special names to symbols a little too securely :) In both algebras $i^2=-1$ and $j^2=1$, *but even so it may be possible, and in fact is the case, that $ij=ji$ in one and $ij=-ji$ in the other.* In fact, in a third algebra, $ij$ could be equal to something else other than $ij$ and $ji completely!

Comment: @moray95 So you can see that they are not really "the same numbers" because they have different relationships in the two algebras.

Comment: Thanks, very much more clear know!

Comment: Special thanks for answering all my questions!

Comment: @moray95 You ask the sort of questions I think abstract algebra teachers enjoy hearing... good luck with your studies!

Comment: Are you an abstract algebra teacher?

Comment: @moray95 Sometimes!

Comment: I guess just for me :D

Answer (score 5):

I think the confusion here comes from the the fact that The Bicomplex numbers and the Quaternions are completely different things that use the same letters.

So $i$,$j$ and $k$ mean different things when they represent Bicomplex numbers and when they represent Quaternions.

Quaternions may be represented as a subset of the real $2\times 2$ matrices, but Bicomplex numbers cannot. They may however be represented as $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb C$. So I can set

$$ I = \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf i & 0\\ 
0 & \mathbf i 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ J = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$ K = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbf i\\ 
\mathbf i & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Where $\mathbf i\in\mathbb C$ is the square root of $-1$.

You can check that all the calculations work.

As for where they come from, inventing crazy algebras was considered a very gentlemanly pursuit in the 1840s and someone just wrote down the rules and noticed it "worked" as an algebra.

Comment: So far, I noticed 2 different representations for $i$ which are $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\ 
0 & i
\end{pmatrix}$. I understand where they come from (both squared gives -I) but can we say that these two matrices are equals? They both represent the same number but their coefficients are different...

Comment: +1 for the gentlemanly pursuit comment :) It's so true...

Comment: @moray95 You can't conclude that they are equal.  All you can conclude is that both of them possess the property that $x^2 = \begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$.  But as you see, this is not a sufficient condition for two matrices to be equal.  Analogously you can't conclude from $a^2 = b^2$ that $a=b$.

Comment: @moray95 I tried to give you an answer, but it's a bit of a philosophical question so  I can't. Although the answer is in fact no. as MJD pointed out.

Comment: As a minor note, your model gives Tessarines, rather than bicomplex numbers (though they are isomorphic). I like Tessarines more because $j^2=1$, like in spit-complex numbers, so it is like adding split-complex to complex numbers (and we do not need a special symbol for the 4th unity). Also, in Tessarines the signs of squares alternate for unities, which makes compuatations easier. https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.527.356&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 0):

The algebra you discribed in the question is tessarines.

So, there are two matrical representations of tessarines.

1. For a tessarine $z=w_1+w_2i+w_3j+w_4ij$ the matrix representation is as follows:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 {w_0} & -{w_1} & {w_2} & -{w_3} \\
 {w_1} & {w_0} & {w_3} & {w_2} \\
 {w_2} & -{w_3} & {w_0} & -{w_1} \\
 {w_3} & {w_2} & {w_1} & {w_0} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

One has to use the 4x4 matrix. After performing the operations, the coefficients of the resulting tessarine can be extracted from the first column of the resulting matrix.

2. Alternatively, one can use a 2x2 matrix of the form $z=a+bj=\left(
   \begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    b & a \\
   \end{array}
   \right)$

where both $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers. Since complex numbers are embedded in most computer algebra systems, I prefer the second method.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica, the following code assd support for the split-complex unity `J` along with complex unity `I`. This allows to calculate any expressions with tessarines:

```
 $Pre = If[FreeQ[#, J], #, Module[{tmp},
      
 tmp = Evaluate[
    MatrixFunction[Function[J, #], {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]] // 
   FullSimplify;
       tmp /. {{a_, b_}, {b_, a_}} -> a + J b]] &;

J^I

Out= 1/2 (1 + (-1)^I) + 1/2 J (1 - Cosh[Pi] + Sinh[Pi])
```